# JFrame show labels in a scroll panel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jscrollpane

I'm making a frame who needs to show labels in a Scroll Panel, but after I add the labels the scroll don't work.

[image: Example]

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(1, 1, 210, 259);

    panel.add(scrollPane);

    JPanel roomList = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(roomList);
    roomList.setLayout(null);

    int x=0;
    for(String l : list) {
        JLabel c = new JLabel(l+" "+x);
        c.setBounds(new Rectangle(1, 1+x*11, 191, 14));
        roomList.add(c);
        x++;
    }
```

I'm sure the list has more than 22.

I don't know how to google it!

Comment: I would change `roomList.setLayout(null)` to `roomList.setLayout(new BoxLayout(roomList, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic problem is, you don't understand how the layout management API works, or how to replace it's functionality when you choose to discard it.

You problem starts here:

```
roomList.setLayout(null);
```

There's a lot of work going on in the background which provides a great deal of information to various parts of the API, while on the surface, the layout management API is not complex, the role it plays is.

The `JScrollPane` will use the component's `preferredSize` to determine when it should display the scrollbars.  Since you've done away with this automated calculation, the `JScrollPane` has nothing to go on

For more information, have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

As a simple example...

[image: Simple Scroll Example]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new TestPane());
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                add(new JLabel("Row " + index), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 32;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 32;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return getPreferredSize().width <= getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

This example implements the `Scrollable` interface, this is not always required, but is used, for this example, to provide a hint to the `JScrollPane` about the preferred size of the viewable area it should use, otherwise it will attempt to use the component's `preferredSize`.

But, as has already been suggested, there are other, simpler and more optimised solutions available to you.

If your information is simple enough, you can use a `JList` to list a number of values in a vertical manner, see [How to use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

If you information is in a more complex structure, you could use a `JTable`, which provides a row and column style structure.  See [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information

Comment: I had a feeling it was related to preferred sizes, and now I know how. Good answer! +1

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think JList is better for me!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using jLists instead of JScrollPanes ?

They're very easily implemented, look great and work like a charm.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for(String l : list) {
    model.addElement(l);
}

yourList.setModel(model);
```

Where `list` is the list with the room data and `yourList` is the jList.

Comment: JList is better for what I need, Thanks!